# acciones git dejaron de funcionar en android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

autofetch failed y las acciones gitdejaron de funcionar desde que cloné nuevamente el repo.

Ahora cada vez que necesite hacer pull, push o merge, debo hacerlo desde la consola y el proceso es un poco demorado porque toca acceder a git lab con usuario y contraseña con cada accion.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Algún log de errores o mensaje relacionados? Es en GitLab? Es un servidor privado o en la nube? Por favor, ve a [edit] y haz una descripción más detallas de tu problema. En su estado actual requiere un alto grado de adivinación y la idea es darte respuestas útiles.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub aplicó una función de tokens para los proyectos.

Por lo que se necesita generar un token para tus proyectos y una vez iniciado
cualquier clonación de repositorios debes acceder con el.

puedes hacer uso del siguiente comando después de ingresar tus datos

git config --global credential.helper store

con eso los guardas y ya no debería pedirlos.

Saludos. Espero que te sirva.